# Azure SQL Datawarehouse - JVM SimpleDateFormat support

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, datetime-format, azure-synapse

I'm currently hitting a limitation on Azure SQL DW when converting timestamps from the [JVM SimpleDateFormat domain](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)
to [SQL DW's DateFormat domain.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935026.aspx)

In my current scenario, we're using Spark to perform data cleanup, when data is written out as a CSV file, its written out as a timestamp in the following format:

- "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX"
- 2001-07-04**T**12:08:56.235-07:00

Looking at DateTimeOffset under the DATE_FORMAT options, the bolded **T** in the above output isn't supported.

Is there any way to directly interpret the incoming string as a DateTime type?

My current strategy is to load it as a VARCHAR and do cleanups later.

Comment: Please provide what do you have / what have you tried so far.

Comment: If I may ask, how is this related to apache-spark ?

Comment: @eliasah has to do with the way Spark formats the output for timestamps, its getting emitted in the [ISO8601 combined Date+Time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations).

With respect to Spark, I wanted to ask if there was a way to make Spark serialize timestamp types to formats which can be read by SQL DW in an external table.

Comment: I think I've asked this question incorrectly, the most distilled version of this question is how to load an ISO8601 combined date time formatted timestamp string into Azure SQL DW.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like unless you transform the datetime itself before it hits SQL DW, it won't be interpreted as datetime due to the T. Your best bet is having it as varchar and then casting it as a datetime in SQL DW as listed here: [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Examples: Azure SQL Data Warehouse and Parallel Data Warehouse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx#Examples:%20Azure%20SQL%20Data%20Warehouse%20and%20Parallel%20Data%20Warehouse)

I would recommend also casting a vote in the [feature request portal](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/307516-sql-data-warehouse/suggestions/9751443-more-flexible-date-formats-in-polybase) for more flexible datetime formats so you don't have to go through this process